# SSRS Espression for String to Date Time format

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript

Hi I have a SQL Stored Procedure to for my SSRS Report.
Below is the query to fetch Date i used.

```
 (CONVERT(CHAR(10), ENTER_DT, 103), '''')
```

I am not in a position to change this query. The Dat Format currently displayed is "DD/MM/YYYY".

I want to display the date format as Below using SSRS Expressions.

```
MM-DD-YYYY
```

Please guide me to do that using SSRS Expresions. PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Display Format instead of converting into TSQL (Stored Procedure), Follow the steps go to textBox Properties, Select Number & Category Custom then Custom Format whatever you want

[image]